# Logic app: Mapping to base64 encoding of dynamic content

Tags: azure-logic-apps

We have a list on a Sharepoint site that we need to copy to a CSV file in a different Azure tenant.  As part of that, we've been asked to take one field containing free-form comments (called "Support Comments") and covert it to base64.  I can access the comments field with no problem:

[image]

I can access the base64 expression:

[image]

Now, how do I get the base64 conversion of a comment?  That is, if "Support Comments" contains "This is a test", I want it to return "VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Q=".  I've tried expressions like this:

```
base64([SupportComments])
```

with variations on quoting types and places, with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the list has items, it needs to be in a for loop to retrieve each item and so you need to use for loop with list values in a `compose` connector and then use the same `compose` connector for conversion(i.e., base64). Here is my logic app

[image]

**RESULTS**

[image]

Comment: I hate this outcome, but it turns out that, whatever the problem is, but suggested solutions *should* work, but neither will.  I created a duplicate of the logic app and, with a couple of small changes to the trigger, of all things, and the variable initialization the solutions worked.  So both are actually correct, it appears, or at least can be applied.  I'm still trying to figure out why that change made it work, but that's another story for another time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your exact example but it's the same concept.  Bottom line, you shouldn't need to type the entire expression in.

Try one of these two approaches ...

#### Approach 1

After typing in `base64()`, click back to the **Dynamic Content** tab and then simply select your `Support comments` content.

**Step 1**

[image: Step 1]

**Step 2**

[image: Step 2]

**Result**

[image: Result]

The expression won't be exactly the same as what's shown but it should yield the same result on your side.

#### Approach 2

Put the dynamic content directly in the field you want it to go to ...

[image: Step 1]

Now go into `Code View` ...

[image: Step 2]

... and update the expression directly.

[image: Step 3]

If the flow doesn't save or it doesn't work then there's something different about your `Support Comments` field that we need to get to the bottom of.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough and documented response.  I figured it should be something straightforward like that.  However, when I go to Dynamic content, Support comments is not in the list.  Almost everything is gone, in fact.  However, if I'm not using an expression, it's in the Dynamic content list.  This is very odd.

Comment: Ok, I’ll update my answer to another option.

Comment: Sometimes there's a `More ...` button next to groups of previous actions in the dynamic content, check that out too.